# Android Firebase: cannot resolve method in firebaseAuth

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

My Android Studio project was working fine until I updated a plugin accidentally in a pop-up suggestion. After that "Firebase Auth" methods are not working. For example:

```
fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
fUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

I get the error "**cannot resolve method getCurrentUser in firebaseAuth**". Similarly, in the following code:

```
ref.child(fAuth.getUid()).child("Orders").child(orderId).orderByChild("orderStatus")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {.....}
```

I get error  "**cannot resolve method getUid in firebaseAuth**". Following is my build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.5.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.vanniktech:android-image-cropper:4.5.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.p32929:EasiestSqlLibrary:1.0.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.p32929:AndroidEasySQL-Library:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'}
```

I get these errors in my whole project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question here. I tried many solutions, but then I got to know I had used a wrong dependency.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:9.1.1'
```

After I have removed it, my project is working.

Hope it will help others.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the following error:

> cannot resolve method getUid in firebaseAuth

Most likely at the following line of code:

```
ref.child(fAuth.getUid())...
```

Because the `fAuth` object is an object of type [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth), a class does **not** contain any method called `getUid()`. If you need the UID of the authenticated user, you have to call `.getCurrentUser()` first. In code that would be:

```
ref.child(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())...
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, I also get error on .getCurrentUser()

Comment: I am not even getting suggestions of "getCurrentUser()" and "getUid"

Comment: Have you tried `ref.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())...` as well? Does it work? If not, are you sure you have added the correct `import`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. In this case error highlights in .getCurrentUser(). Import is also correct because I have not changed it. It was working for about a month. Problem arised only after plugin update.

Comment: Show me the import you're using.

Comment: My imports are: import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

Comment: @Tasneem which plugin you updated ?

Comment: Hey Tasneem. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?